# routing problem after rails 2.3 to rails 3 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my routes I have:

```
namespace :pm do
  match '/' => 'base#index', :as => :root
  resources :projects do
```

Also I have app/controllers/pm/projects_controller.rb

When going in browser to /pm/projects/1, I should have params[:id] == 1, but instead getting empty params hash in action.

In log file:

```
Started GET "/pm/projects/1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Sep 14 15:01:22 +0400 2011
Processing by Pm::ProjectsController#show as HTML
```

So controller and action are recognised normally

Has anybody seen such thing? Where could be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It expects a namespaced controller.

```
resources :projects, :controller => "projects"
```

Comment: Tried to do so, it didn't help.